# NHibernate varying the way it creates DateTime based queries based on the day of the month

Tags: nhibernate, datetime

I am getting some weird behaviour on how NHibernate is sending queries to the database on DateTimeOffset fields. Given the following example:

```
DateTimeOffset? myDate = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 3, 17, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
var test = HibernateSession.Query<ExampleEntity>().Where(c => c.DateTimeOffsetField > myDate).ToList();
DateTimeOffset? myDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
var test2 = HibernateSession.Query<ExampleEntity>().Where(c => c.DateTimeOffsetField > myDate2).ToList();
```

Using NHibernate Profiler to look at the SQL generated, the first query shows up as

```
exampleentity0_.[DateTimeOffsetField] > '17/03/2012 00:00:00 +01:00' /* @p0 */
```

the second as

```
exampleentity0_.[DateTimeOffsetField] > '2012-01-02T23:00:00.00' /* @p0 */
```

Notice the different formatting on the dates? If the day of the month is greater than 12, it uses the first format, if it is less than 12 it uses the second. This is causing errors when we have dates in the first format as SQL server cannot convert the string to a valid Date as it is looking for month 17 (as this example). This is driving me nuts!!

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?
Is it possible to tell NHibernate to always use the yyyy-MM-dd format?

Thanks
Tom

p.s. using FluentNHibernate for the mapping and configuration. An example of the mapping would be

```
Map(a => a.DateTimeOffsetField).Not.Nullable();
```

...i.e nothing unusual..

Answer (score 0):

I have "fixed" this issue by changing the sql server instance to use a British time culture so that is accepts both values created by NHibernate... still be interested to know why these differences occur though.